# What is the difference between openssl pkeyutl -sign and openssl rsautl -sign

Tags: rsa, openssl

What is the difference between `openssl pkeyutl -sign -pkeyopt digest:sha256` and `openssl rsautl -sign` ? Do they do the same thing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about usage of a specific piece of cryptographic software.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`pkeyutl -sign` with an RSA key (and `rsa_padding_mode` defaulted to `pkcs1` which specifically means pkcs1-v1_5) AND `-pkeyopt digest:$hash` does steps 2-6 of EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5-ENCODE in section 9.2 of rfc3447, then step 2 of RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5-SIGN in section 8.2.
In other words it does everything but hash the data (but it does check the *length* of the input hash). Note that if the hash *name* you specify here is different from the hash you actually used, the resulting signature will not verify correctly.

`rsautl -sign` (similarly defaulted) does only steps 4-6 and step 2. In other words, it does NOT add the ASN.1 AlgorithmIdentifier encoding to the raw hash, so you need to do that yourself if you want your signatures to be understood and accepted by others. `pkeyutl -sign` WITHOUT `-pkeyopt digest` also skips the ASN.1 encoding.

For completeness, `dgst -$hash -sign` or its abbreviated form `$hash -sign` with an RSA key does the whole job: hash, ASN.1 encode, pad 01FF..00, and modexp.